# convert from text to date format in excel

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have 2 text as below want to convert to date in excel

```
2/10/2001 4:00:00 AM    
2/10/2001 12:30:00 PM
```

I tried =DATEVALUE() and TEXT(A1, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm") in excel which returns me error

[image]

I also tried to calculate these 2 dates which also return me error

[image]

Comment: Only `DATEVALUE()` will not work as it has time value. So sum that two value like `=Datevalue(A1)+Timevalue(A1)`

Comment: Those do not appear to be text but true dates formatted to look that way.  Change the number format to General and see if they change what is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula

```
=TEXT(--LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1)+(--MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,100)),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

This simple formula should also work- format the resulting cell as `mm/dd/e hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

```
=TRIM(DATEVALUE(A1))+TRIM(TIMEVALUE(A1))
```

`FILTERXML()` will also work.

```
=TEXT(SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<3]")),"mm/dd/e hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

[image]

Comment: Still get an error  @Harun24HR just add a pic in the question to show the error

Comment: @Jerr567 What about other formulas?

Comment: not working either should I format the colunm first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. When you enter those values into a spreadsheet, Excel understands them as date/time values. No conversion is necessary. You can perform date/time arithmetic on them as is.

[image]

Cell A1 & B1 show the values I copied from your question and pasted into the worksheet. C1 shows the time interval in hours.

Comment: I think it's showing as text format in excel  @Nicholas Hunter